# jQuery function not working on AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Lufia</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $('#mydiv').html( 'Loading... ').load('welcome.html');
        $(this).hide();
      });
    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>ajax</button><div id="mydiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**In this code when button is clicked in `midiv` `welcome.html` is loaded and button gets hidden.**

`welcome.html` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Lufia</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>New Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

This new button's `onClick` is not working. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple solution here - you'll need to use the jQuery `.live()` function to add an event handler for the new button.

```
$("#newButton").live('click',function(){
  // Do stuff here
});
```

When you initially created the `.click()` handler, that second `button` was not yet in the DOM, so jQuery could not attach an event handler to it.  The `.live()` function will work for any element that is already in the DOM and also any element that will be added in the future (e.g. from an ajax call).

You might want to give your new button (from the ajax call) a new and different ID as the selector `$("button")` will capture both your buttons (even though one is hidden).

---

### NOTE!

Since version 1.7 of jQuery, the `live()` method [has been deprecated!](http://api.jquery.com/live/). As of version 1.9 this function will be removed completely... The correct way to deal with event handlers of these dynamically added elements is now to use the [`on()` function.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You will have to change the `.click()` function to the `.live()` function that I have given as an example.

Answer (score 4):

Live is deprecated. You should use on.

**$(document).on("click","button", function () {**

is the live/delegated format of on.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

Because the button hasn't got anything bound to it.

So in welcome.html you would have to add code to handle it.

Alternatively; You could bind the onclick handler in a function and then on the ajax.done() method bind that handler to the new button.

Best method would be to do something like: *Note* This has not been tested AT all.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var buttonClickEvent = function(){
  $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
  }).done(function(results) { 
    $('#mydiv').html(results);
    $('button').live('click',buttonClickEvent);
  });
}

$("button").click(buttonClickEvent);

</script>
```

Alternatively:

`welcome.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Lufia</title>

<body><button>New Button</button>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       //do something
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 Depending on how much and exactly *what* content is being loaded in the AJAX call, your second option would defiantly be a good alternative...

Comment: Your second way is very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Check properly that you given the right path for jquery in your code. It might be the reason that the code is not working.....

Answer (score -1):

It is usually because of the files included incorrectly.

I have included the jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js
and it distoryed my maskings.

After 2 hours of code checking, when I removed the file. The problem was solved;

:)

Comment: This is a very low quality answer AND it was posted 15 days after the OP Accepted an answer. I see that this helped you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386852/jquery-mask-is-not-working-for-loaded-content/10394552#10394552), but it still is not a relevant answer for this question.