# jQuery mask is not working for loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, mask

when the contents are loaded with ajax, the mask is not working on the input text.

What Should I do?

with thanks

Code:

```
$.ajax({url: path, data: {action:'create_form_profile'}, timeout:5000, type:"POST", success: function(data) {
    $("#_content").html(data);
    {
        $("#birth_date").mask("9999/99/99");
    }


    $("input:hidden").click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = "logout.php";
        sho‌​w_exit();
    });
}
});
```

Comment: $.ajax({url: _path,
 data: {action:'create_form_profile'},
 timeout:5000,
 type:"POST",
 success: function(data) { $("#_content_").html(data); 
{$("#birth_date").mask("9999/99/99");});
$("input:hidden").click(function(event){ window.location.href="logout.php" ; show_exit(); });
   },
});

Comment: {$("#birth_date").mask("9999/99/99");});

Comment: place your code in your question post

Answer (score 4):

For me works this in ajax callback:

```
$('.phone').unmask().mask(phoneMask);
```

I don't understand why adding the same mask second time disables it..

Answer (score 0):

fire a change event on the input after changing its contents via ajax.

if the entire input comes from ajax then run the mask plugin on it and then fire the change event.

IE:

```
   $("#birth_date").mask("9999/99/99").change();
```

Comment: Dear mkoryak thanks for you note. but I found the problem when I had included the file jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js. when I exclude the file, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason ;)

jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js was the cause.

I have the following js files included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/_links.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/_mask.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/_general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/_jq.js"></script>
```

and when I removed the second file, it was so